# h2 with sifr enabled duplicates

Tags: sifr, duplicates

I'm having problems with h2 headlines. sifr does replace the text, but as soon as it replaces the text inside h2 tags, after that it repeats the text in h2 but without sifr. Can anyone point me to the right direction what could cause this problem? Tnx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't properly loaded the sIFR stylesheets which will hide the alternative HTML text.